# Remove the last digit from a String

Tags: java, string, substring, calculator

I'm creating a Java calculator (only buttons - like T9 keys) in an Android XML Application, and I want to fix the "Cancel" button.

When I click it, I want to cancel the last digit from a String that contains only numbers (or '.', because you can also add '.' to write decimal numbers). 
There is a problem: if the user writes an int number (34) and I convert it to double, it becomes 34.0 and, if I cancel the last digit, it cancels the 0.

I also tried with `String.substring(start,end)`, but it doesn't work...
Have you got any suggestions about the cancel handle? Thank you!

This is the function that cancels the last digit.

```
/* tv -> TextView
- tvResult contains what the user writes and the result when he clicks "=", - tvCalc contains the calc that the user is entering.
For example, if the user writes with the 0-9 buttons and the operator of the operations, in tvCalc there will be "34+50=", and in tvResult "84" */

public void handleCancel(View v) {
    //tv -> TextView, tvResult contains what the user writes and the result when he clicks "=", tvCalc contains the calc that the user is entering: for example if user writes with the 0-9 buttons and the operator of the operations, in tvCalc there will be "34+50=", and in tvResult "84"

    if (tvResult.length() == 0) {
        errorToast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error! There's nothing to cancel!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        errorToast.show();
    } else {
        tvResult.setText(tvResult.toString().substring(0, tvResult.toString().length() - 1))

        if (tvCalc.toString().contains("=")) {
            tvCalc.setText(tvResult.toString());
            operand1 = tvResult.toString();
        } else {
            tvCalc.setText(tvCalc.toString().substring(0, tvCalc.toString().length() - 1));
            if (operator == "") operand1 = tvResult.toString();
            else {
                operand2 = tvResult.toString();
                try {
                    int conv = Integer.parseInt(tvCalcolo.toString());
                    operazione = "";
                } catch(Exception e) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The function that adds the choice of the user:

```
public void userChoice(View v)
{
    Button clicked=(Button)findViewById(v.getId());
    String choice=clicked.getText().toString();
    try
    {
        int number=Integer.parseInt(choice);
        if (operator=="") 
        {
            operand1+=choice;
            if (tvCalc.toString().contains("=")) tvCalc.setText(operand1);
        } else operand2+=choice;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (choice.equals('.'))
        {
            if (operator=="") operand1+=choice;
            else operand2+=choice;
        } else 
        {
            if (operand2!="")
            {
                handleEqual(v);
                operand1=tvResult.toString();
            }
            operator=choice;
            tvCalc.append(operator);
            tvResult.setText("");
            return;
        }
    }

    tvCalc.append(choice);
    tvResult.append(choice);
}
```

I edited the function "handleCancel" thanks to Cardinal System:

```
public void handleCancel (View v)
{

    double d;
    try
    {
        d=Double.parseDouble(tvRisultato.toString());
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        bCanc.setText("Error"); //It's the button 'Cancel'
    }

    String newVal;
    if (d%1==0) 
    {
        int val=(int)d;
        newVal=String.valueOf(val);
        newVal=newVal.substring(0,newVal.length()-1);
    } else 
    { 
        newVal=String.valueOf(d);
        newVal=newVal.substring(0,newVal.length()-1);
        if (newVal.endsWith(".")) 
        { 
            newVal=newVal.substring(0,newVal.length()-1);
        }
    }

    tvResult.setText(newVal);

    if ((tvCalc.toString().contains("+")||tvCalc.toString().contains("-")||tvCalc.toString().contains("*")||tvCalc.toString().contains("/")||tvCalc.toString().contains("^"))&&tvCalc.toString().contains("="))
    {
        tvCalc.setText(tvResult.toString());
        operand1=tvResult.toString();
    } else if ((tvCalc.toString().contains("+")||tvCalc.toString().contains("-")||tvCalc.toString().contains("*")||tvCalc.toString().contains("/")||tvCalc.toString().contains("^"))&&!tvCalc.toString().contains("="))
    {
        if (tvCalc.toString().endsWith("+")||tvCalc.toString().endsWith("-")||tvCalc.toString().endsWith("*")||tvCalc.toString().endsWith("/")||tvCalc.toString().endsWith("^")) operator="";
        tvCalc.setText(tvCalc.toString().substring(0,tvCalc.toString().length()-1));
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: If the User doesn't add the decimal point him/her self then don't programmatically add it either until the **=** button is selected. **Cancel** should always work against what the User actually enters otherwise a lot more code is required.

Comment: Is `tvResult` a TextView?

Comment: Yes, `tvResult` is a TextView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps you:

```
// Let's make it a double so we have something to work with.
double d = Double.parseDouble(tvResult.getText().toString());

String newText;
if (d % 1 == 0) { // See if the number is a whole number
    int i = (int) d; // If it is, cast it to an int to get rid of the decimal
    newText = String.valueOf(i); // Parse it to a string so we can clip off the end
    newText = newText.substring(0, newText.length() - 1); // Clip off the end
} else { 
    // If it's not a whole number, just parse it to a string.
    newText = String.valueOf(d);
    newText = newText.substring(0, newText.length() - 1); // Clip off the end
    if (newText.endsWith(".")) { 
        // If the number we clipped off was a tenth, clip off the decimal
        newText = newText.substring(0, newText.length() - 1);
    }
}

tvResult.setText(newText);
```

Comment: Hi! I added your code in my project but there's an error here:

`double d = Double.parseDouble(tvResult.toString());`

I added a try-catch and I viewed `tvResult.toString()` and it said `android.widget.TextView{...` and lots of numbers, so in the String there isn't only what the user writes, but this id (I think), and I can't convert it to a double. What can I do to split this String or to take only the part that I'm interested?

Comment: Hey!! Any idea?

Comment: @coder999 I need to see the complete error message to know exactly what the problem is.

Comment: First of all, I added the code of the new `handleCancel`.
I don't receive any errors when I delete the last character in the String, but when there's the try-catch, it goes to `bCanc.setText("Error");` and when it views the content of the String of tvCalc, I see `"android.widget.TextView{42284730 V.ED.... .........0,8-432,53#7f080003 app:id/tvCalc*the number I input*"`
How can I work with only the number I input?

Comment: @coder999 I updated my answer. Don't use `TextView#toString()`, use `TextView.getText().toString();`

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll try it when I can and I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could fulfill your requirements at least in two ways:

1. pattern searching symbols to be removed (something like (.0|\d|+|-|*|/) ) - would not recommend
2. remembering last input string before new digit/operation is added. F.e. on button . pressed you would remember your current input to calculator to variable and in case you need to cancel, you simply set current input line to that variable

Hope my suggestions were helpfull.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When the user clicks on a number or an operator, I add his choice with .append()

Comment: @coder999 yes, before you call append, you could additionally save whole string of  input in your calculator (due to the immutable nature of Strings) Could you also update your question with part of code, were you add symbols to string?

Comment: @coder999 see, before this method (before button declaration), you can save current state of your application, by calling tvCalc.getText().toString() and saving it to class'es variable.  Do same with other variables that might change in this method. This way your cancel operation will always guarantee to come back to previous state. Afterwards, by doing in such manner, you can move memory variables into another class, put changes into limited size stack and have a memory able of cancellation several times without application errors. In cancel method right now you would just call tvCalc.setText